# Custom ListView Inside ListFragment

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the ListFragment and assign an adapter to it.
I tried many different methods, but still the app crashes and won't start.

Here is what I have done:

fragment_five.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bg11">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

FiveFragment.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FiveFragment extends ListFragment {

    public FiveFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_five, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        String items[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list5);

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), items);
        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    }


}
```

and here is the CustomListAdapter that I am using... I am sure it works cause I have tested elsewhere

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String texts[];

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, String[] texts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.texts = texts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return texts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView details;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.details = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.details);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        holder.details.setText(texts[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

When I use the simple ArrayAdapter everything is ok but when I use the Custom Adapter the app crashes... it doesn't matter that which adapter I use either the CustomArrayAdapter or the CustomBaseAdapter it just doesn't work.

If you know any way around this please help!

Comment: list_item.xml has not R.id. details !

Comment: list_item.xml is a resource file, there is just a textView inside of it, the getView will deal with it ,, there is no need for R.id here

Comment: Here is the stacktrace: is's huge!!!         AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.tech.spring.sarbazi, PID: 15031
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at com.tech.spring.sarbazi.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:54)
                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
                                                       at   ... and so on ....

Comment: If you require any further info feel free to tell me...

Comment: this Fragment is actually a Tab, it is a part of a ViewPager. Everything is ok without the Custom List View ,,, Even the simple ArrayAdapter works fine but I think I need a Custom Adapter for my list....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this problem...

FiveFragment.java should be like this:

```
public class FiveFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
private String items[];

public FiveFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list5);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_five, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You Clicked on: " + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

and the CustomListAdapter:

```
private LayoutInflater myInflater;
private String shopList[];

public ShopListAdapter(Context context, String shopList[]) {
    myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.shopList = shopList;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvTitle.setText(shopList[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

This code solved the problem completely...